# union and difference of sets in Clojure

Tags: clojure, set, union

I am reading the Clojure section of the book [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435659X). It says:

```
You can merge two sets, like this:
user=> (clojure.set/union #{:skywalker} #{:vader})
#{:skywalker :vader}
Or compute the difference:
(clojure.set/difference #{1 2 3} #{2})
```

This doesn't work on my version (`Clojure 1.7.0` and Java version`"1.8.0_51"` ):

```
user=> (clojure.set/difference #{1 2 3} #{4})
ClassNotFoundException clojure.set  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (:-1)

user=> (clojure.set/union #{:skywalker} #{:vader})
ClassNotFoundException clojure.set  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (:-1)
```

In [Clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/difference) shorter function names are used in the examples, but that also doesn't work:

```
user=> (difference #{1 2} #{2 3})
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: difference in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:14:1)
```

Why am I receiving these errors and how should I fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Namespaces other than `clojure.core` and `user` are only loaded if someone loads them. The standard way to load a namespace is with `require`.

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])

(set/union ...)
```